# R: how to sort a vector with customized comparison method

Tags: r, sorting

I've been searching for a solution, but haven't found one so far. I saw many people have asked such questions, but got no answers or answers not working for me.

Suppose I have a vector as shown in the codes below and sort it with the R sort function, I'll get the result with g10 as the second element instead as the last element.  So what I'm looking for is a way to supply a comparison function of my own to the sort function, so the sort function will call my function to compare two elements to determine their order (e.g. when my function is called with 'g10', 'g2' as the arguments, my function can separate each argument into letters and digits and compare letters and digits separately and return -1, 0, or 1 according to my own rules).  Such feature is available in many other languages, such as c, Perl, etc.  I appreciate it if you can give an example of working codes with my vector if you know a way. Thanks.

```
> groups <- c('g10', 'g2', 'g5', 'g9', 'g4', 'g8', 'g1', 'g3', 'g6', 'g7')
> groups <- sort(groups)
> groups
 [1] "g1"  "g10" "g2"  "g3"  "g4"  "g5"  "g6"  "g7"  "g8"  "g9"
```

Comment: And what are those rules?

Comment: What have you tried so far that didn't work?

Comment: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gtools/versions/3.5.0/topics/mixedsort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a function like `sort_by` in the `funprog` package.

```
library(stringr)
library(funprog)

f <- function(x) as.numeric(str_extract(x, "\\d+"))

groups <- c('g10', 'g2', 'g5', 'g9', 'g4', 'g8', 'g1', 'g3', 'g6', 'g7')

sort_by(groups, f)
# [1] "g1"  "g2"  "g3"  "g4"  "g5"  "g6"  "g7"  "g8"  "g9"  "g10"
```

Here it sorts `groups` according to the numbers contained in each group. You can supply multiple functions to `sort_by`:

```
f1 <- function(x) str_extract(x, "^[a-z]+")
f2 <- function(x) as.numeric(str_extract(x, "\\d+"))

groups <- c('g10', 'a2', 'f5', 'g9', 'g4', 'b8', 'c1', 'b3', 'a6', 'c17')

sort_by(groups, f1, f2)
# [1] "a2"  "a6"  "b3"  "b8"  "c1"  "c17" "f5"  "g4"  "g9"  "g10"
```

Here the data are sorted according to the "prefixes" and then according to the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a base R solution using `order` + `gsub`, i.e.,

```
r <- groups[order(as.numeric(gsub("\\D","",groups)))]
```

such that

```
> r
 [1] "g1"  "g2"  "g3"  "g4"  "g5"  "g6"  "g7"  "g8"  "g9" 
[10] "g10"
```